# How to add custom fonts to matplotlib plots in tkinter executable?

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, fonts

I am building a tkinter application that generates charts based on various user inputs. The charts are then displayed in a canvas within the GUI and the user can download them.

When I package the script into an executable using pyinstaller and share with my colleagues, they are unable to see the custom font in their matplotlib plots, and they see the default matplotlib font instead. They are also unable to download the plot as an svg (not sure if this is a related issue).

My colleagues have the font file installed on their computers. This is the code I am using to locate the font and use it in the plots but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager
import os 

font_file = 'Barlow-Medium.ttf' 
font_path = font_manager.findfont(font_manager.FontProperties(family='Barlow Medium')) 
if os.path.isfile(font_path): 
  custom_font = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=font_path)
  plt.rcParams\['font.family'\] = custom_font.get_name()
```

Interestingly, I am using Barlow for the GUI interface as well, and it is visible to my colleagues. So the issue is something to do with matplotlib but I can't seem to figure it out.